# I'm using the Scrapy spider and the CSS selector but can't remove empty spaces. Can you help me?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using a spider to collect some information on events off a website. I'm using the css selector and not xpath but I am having trouble removing the spaces.

I've tried Xpath but I feel I may have done it wrong. I'm only having success using the CSS.selector

```
def parse(self, response):

    items = AiaaeventsItem()

    title = response.css('.item-list__title::text').extract()

    date = response.xpath('.//p[@class="item-list__date"]/text()').extract()
```

'title': ['\n                        ',
           '\n'
           '                2019 AAS/AIAA Astrodynamics Specialist Conference\n'
           '            ',
           '\n                        ',
           '\n'
           '                2019 Regional Leadership Conference\n'
           '            ',
           '\n                        ',

{'date': ['\n                11 August - 15 August 2019\n            ',
          '\n                18 August 2019\n            ',
          '\n                19 August - 22 August 2019\n            ',
          '\n                22 August - 24 August 2019\n            ',

Comment: The spaces are in the \n. I've tried adding .strip() after .extract() but didn't work. :/ I'm pretty new to programming.

Comment: I don't fully understand what exactly is your desired output, but to get rid of '\n' completely, you may use this:
`title = [item.replace('\n', '') for item in title if item is not '\n']`
If you wish to keep '\n' in the text but not as a solo element, use this:
`title = [item for item in title if item is not '\n']`.
Plus info on the `.strip()`: that works only on strings. It cuts out only spaces at the start&end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Just a general note: Scrapy suggests using .get() and .get_all() nowadays. https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#extract-and-extract-first

The generic solution to clean up exported test is to use a Scrapy output processor. https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-input-and-output-processors has a good overview. [Cleaning data scraped using Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43539407/cleaning-data-scraped-using-scrapy) kinda looks like a related answer.

That being said, if you only want to clean up a limited amount of extracted text and going the full output processor rule is too much work, I'd iterate over the output and just call strip() or replace() on the string.
Python list comprehension is great for that.

Example use:

```
>>> title = ['\n ', '\n 2019 AAS/AIAA Astrodynamics Specialist Conference\n ', '\n ', '\n 2019 Regional Leadership Conference\n ', '\n ']
>>> date = ['\n 11 August - 15 August 2019\n ', '\n 18 August 2019\n ', '\n 19 August - 22 August 2019\n ', '\n 22 August - 24 August 2019\n ']

# Iterate over each item in title and print it as a list
>>> [x for x in title]
['\n ', '\n 2019 AAS/AIAA Astrodynamics Specialist Conference\n ', '\n ', '\n 2019 Regional Leadership Conference\n ', '\n ']

# Iterate over each item but actually run strip() on the string.
>>> [x.strip() for x in title]
['', '2019 AAS/AIAA Astrodynamics Specialist Conference', '', '2019 Regional Leadership Conference', '']

# Same, but skip empty results
>>> [x.strip() for x in title if len(x.strip())]
['2019 AAS/AIAA Astrodynamics Specialist Conference', '2019 Regional Leadership Conference']

# Same for the date results
>>> [x.strip() for x in date if len(x.strip())]
['11 August - 15 August 2019', '18 August 2019', '19 August - 22 August 2019', '22 August - 24 August 2019']
```

Comment: I think this would work, but I ended up doing it a different way using expressions.

        title = [' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)', t)) for t in title]
        date = [' '.join(re.findall(r'(\w+)', t)) for t in date]
        title = [t for t in title if t]
        date = [d for d in date if d]